# PowerShell Property for show inside folders for a document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

How to get the  property for getting "Show items inside folders" within a document library's advanced settings using PowerShell script.I am having 3 folders and I do not want these folders to be seen in the view.So I want to hide this.Manually I went to the settings and I am changing the "show items inside folders" option. But I have some 100 plus sub sites and each sub site has 8 libraries.

```
    $mysiteurl = "http://server1:123/sites/mysiteURL"
    $msitee = Get-SPSite $mysiteurl
    #web =  $msitee.Rootweb
      foreach($list in $web.Lists) 
        {     
        if($list.BaseType -eq  "DocumentLibrary") 
              {
           $items = $mlist.items
        foreach ($item in $items)
              {
              }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change default view property like:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://test.com"
$doclib = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]
$view = $doclib.Views["All Documents"]
$view.Scope = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewScope]::Recursive
$view.Update()
```

Where "http://test.com" - site URL, "Shared Documents" - name of list/library, "All Documents" - default view name.

Comment: Spot on answer. I just think your bold text has mangled the display with extraneous tags.